# Partition of n into k distinct partitions modulo $p$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions

Given $N$ and $K$ we have to find the number of partitions of $N$ into at most $K$ parts modulo $p$.
I was wondering if there was any formula to calculate this type of query.
I know about the recurrence formula $p_k(n)=p_k(n−k)+p_{k−1}(n)$ also about the ferrers diagram
But this can be used when $N$ and $K$ are small
***I need to find for $1\leq 
 N,K \leq2*10^5$***

Comment: Is it the parts that are being taken modulo $p$, or is it the number of partitions that's being taken modulo $p$?

Comment: Number of parts modulo p like  $p_3(5)$ = 5,14,23,113,122 so count is 5 as there are 5 ways to represent it  and this modulo 11 is 5 and this modulo 3 is 2

Answer (score 1):

> But this can be used when $N$ and $K$ are small
>   ***I need to find for $1\leq   N,K \leq2*10^5$***

Those *are* small.

That aside, a little thought experiment. Suppose that a nice formula were known for $p_k(n) \bmod m$. There are easy upper bounds on $p_k(n)$: for example, [$p_k(n) \leq (n-k+1)^{k-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23537/5676). Substitute for $m$ and our nice formula for $p_k(n) \bmod (n-k+1)^{k-1}$ is just a nice formula for $p_k(n)$. But [I don't see a nice formula](http://oeis.org/A000009) in OEIS, and this is a well-studied and well-referenced sequence, so it's very unlikely that one is known.